# Is there a way of adding tinymce plugin in this gem refinerycms-tinymce?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, refinerycms, tinymce-plugins

I'm using refinerycms-tinymce gem in my rails app and i want to use new plugins in the tinymce editor like [bootsrap-widgets](https://pluginza.com/plugins/bootstrap-widgets)

Is there any simple way of doing that or changing the default configuration of tinymce?

I've tried to create an initializer like this:

```
Refinery::Tinymce.configure do |config|
  config.plugins = 'bootstrap-widgets'
  config.editor_settings = {
    toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image'
  }
end
```

but i didn't succeed yet.

**EDIT**

For example:

1. When i removed "| link image"
2. restart server
3. Result => i still get the link and image item in the editor

Comment: When you say you didn't succeed yet, what is the problem? Are you seeing an error of some kind.

Please provide more context about what you've tried and the error/warning message you receive.

Comment: Thank you for you response. I meant that the change i made is not shown in the editor. (i edited my questions). I don't get any errors anyway. 
I'm not sure if i do it right